# LISP - Modify string

Tags: strings, lisp, common-lisp

I have to write a program that changes a string's vowels, consonants and other symbols into C, V respectively 0. I've done this but I wonder if there is a more efficient and elegant way to do it. Would appreciate input.

```
(defun string-to-list (string)
(loop for char across string collect char))

(defun is-vowel (char) (find char "aeiou" :test #'char-equal))

(defun is-consonant (char) (find char "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz" :test #'char-equal))

(defun letter-type (char)
(if (is-vowel char) "V"
(if (is-consonant char) "C"
"0")))

(defun analyze-word (word-string)
(loop for char across word-string collect (letter-type char)))
```

Moreover, I would like to make it a string, how could I do that? Should I define a function that would iterate through the list and make it a string or is it an easier way to do it?

I've got it, for the ones interested, the code is below. Used map to do it.

```
(defun string-to-list (string)
(loop for char across string collect char))

(defun is-vowel (char) (find char "aeiou" :test #'char-equal))

(defun is-consonant (char) (find char "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz" :test #'char-equal))

(defun analyze_word (word-string)
(loop for char across word-string collect (letter-type char)))

(defun letter-type (char)
  (cond ((find char "aeiou" :test #'char-equal) #\V)
        ((alpha-char-p char) #\C)
        (t #\0)))

(defun change_string (string)
(map 'string #'letter-type "analyze-word")
)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, [proper indentation](http://dept-info.labri.u-bordeaux.fr/~idurand/enseignement/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html) helps a lot. I do appreciate you not putting the closing parens on separate lines though. Thank you.

```
(defun string-to-list (string)
  (loop for char across string collect char))

(defun is-vowel (char) (find char "aeiou" :test #'char-equal))

(defun is-consonant (char) (find char "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz" :test #'char-equal))

(defun letter-type (char)
  (if (is-vowel char) "V"
      (if (is-consonant char) "C"
      "0")))

(defun analyze-word (word-string)
  (loop for char across word-string collect (letter-type char)))
```

---

We're talking about Common Lisp, so there's no call to go defining your own `string-to-list`, especially if you're doing it in terms of `loop`. You can do the same thing with a `coerce` call.

```
CL-USER> (coerce "an example" 'list)
(#\a #\n #\  #\e #\x #\a #\m #\p #\l #\e)
```

Though now that I look at it, you don't call `string-to-list` anywhere anyway, so we may as well just remove the definition.

```
(defun is-vowel (char) (find char "aeiou" :test #'char-equal))

(defun is-consonant (char) (find char "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz" :test #'char-equal))

(defun letter-type (char)
  (if (is-vowel char) "V"
      (if (is-consonant char) "C"
      "0")))

(defun analyze-word (word-string)
  (loop for char across word-string collect (letter-type char)))
```

---

Common Lisp convention is to use a suffix of `p` or `-p` for predicates, rather than an `is` prefix.

```
(defun vowel-p (char) (find char "aeiou" :test #'char-equal))

(defun consonant-p (char) (find char "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz" :test #'char-equal))

(defun letter-type (char)
  (if (vowel-p char) "V"
      (if (consonant-p char) "C"
      "0")))
```

---

You can use `cond` rather than chaining `if`s. Typically, this makes the intent clearer.

```
(defun letter-type (char)
  (cond ((vowel-p char) "V")
        ((consonant-p char) "C")
        (t "O")))
```

---

If you want to make the result of `analyze-word` a string, you'll need to return a character rather than a string from `letter-type`

```
(defun letter-type (char)
  (cond ((vowel-p char) #\V)
        ((consonant-p char) #\C)
        (t #\O)))
```

At that point, you can `coerce` its result.

```
CL-USER> (coerce (analyze-word "supercalifragilistiwhateverthefuck") 'string)
"CVCVCCVCVCCVCVCVCCVCCVCVCVCCCVCVCC"
```

---

Since your function is taking a sequence of characters, and returning a sequence of characters in the same form, it's actually easier to define `analyze-word` in terms of `map` than in terms of `loop` (in my experience, this is atypical but still worth looking out for).

```
(defun analyze-word (word-string)
  (map 'string #'letter-type word-string))
```

That will take "the function named `letter-type`", apply it to each element of `word-string` and return the resulting `string`. This also saves you from having to coerce its result after the fact.

```
CL-USER> (analyze-word "supercalifragilistiwhateverthefuck")
"CVCVCCVCVCCVCVCVCCVCCVCVCVCCCVCVCC"
```

Take this last point with a grain of salt though, because if you ever need to re-write `analyze-word` to return something like `(list :consonants 21 :vowels 13)`, you'll be right back to `loop`.